# Spring-data-mongodb count error when collection is empty

Tags: mongodb, count, spring-data-mongodb

Whats the diference between this two queries?

This query works, well when exist or not values on collections.

```
@Query(value = "{'request.req_number':?0, 'product.prod_number':?1}", count = true)
int myMethod(String requestNumber, String productNumber){...
```

But this results a Nullpointer, when a collection is empty.

```
    @Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$match':{'request.req_number':?0, 'product.prod_number':?1} }","{'$count':'total'}"}) 
int myMethod(String requestNumber, String productNumber){...
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AggregationUtils.extractSimpleTypeResult(AggregationUtils.java:192) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedAggregation.doExecute(StringBasedAggregation.java:114) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation return 'Object' you should use something like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Count {
    Long total;
}
...
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$match':{'request.req_number':?0, 'product.prod_number':?1} }","{'$count':'total'}"}) 
Count myMethod(String requestNumber, String productNumber){...
```